# Why does shacharit repeat kaddish yatom?

Tags: tefilla, kaddish, shacharis-morning-prayer, chol-weekday

Ashkenazi nussach ends the weekday *shacharit* service with two *kaddish yatom*s: one after "*Aleinu*" and another after the psalm for the day (and seasonal insertions if applicable).  [Ismar Elbogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ismar_Elbogen)'s *Jewish Liturgy: A Comprehensive History* is silent on it.  Why is this done?  Specifically, why is *kaddish yatom* said twice?

Answer (score 4):

[Aruch HaShulchan 55:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=110&hilite=) says that the reason there are 2 Kaddish Yasoms at the end of Shacharis is due to the many Yesomim. (I would presume that only one person said each Kaddish, and this way more Yesomim were able to say a Kaddish at the Tefila).

DoubleAA added in a comment: Recall at the time there were only 2-3 Kaddishes available for mourners per day (after Alenu at Shacharit and Arvit, and in some communities one before Pesukei DiZimra), so allowing one more per day would have a big effect (33%-50% increase).

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  But Aruch HaShulchan caps it at two, rather than, say, adding as many as are needed?

Comment: He definitely caps it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Recall at the time there were only 2-3 Kaddishes available for mourners per day (after Alenu at Shacharit and Arvit, and in some communities one before Pesukei DiZimra), so allowing one more per day would have a big effect (33%-50% increase). Back then if there were 10 mourners in a city (remember lifespans were shorter and disease was more deadly), they'd each only be saying Kaddish once or twice a week, so an extra one per week is a big deal. (Puts some perspective on people nowadays who quibble over saying eg. 6 or 7 per day!)

Comment: @DoubleAA good point, especially when combined with one local shul as opposed to many like in cities today.  Should we edit that into the answer, Gershon?

Comment: @ Monica - Please edit