# How many times do women say Kaddish in shul?

Tags: halacha, number, women, synagogue, kaddish

If only a woman in the shul is saying Kaddish, does she say it once or every time that the siddur says *Kaddish yasom* (the Kaddish for mourners)?

From [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17666/5120), I see that it is permitted for her to say kadish, according to R' Moshe.

But maybe it is only one kaddish and the obligation to say the rest of the kaddish yosom is not on the woman but on the congregation and there is no reason for her to say it.

Comment: If you would include why you think either of those is reasonable, that would make this a stronger question.

Comment: @Scimonster this is better?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the obligation to say the rest of the kaddish yosom is not on the woman but on the congregation"?

Comment: @GershonGold I do not know anything about this It just does not feel right that the minyan waits a few times for her to say Kaddish

Comment: So according to your feelings the Minyan should never wait for her. Why wait even once? Feelings are not what determine Halacha.

Comment: @GershonGold they just cause questions

Comment: -1 Would you tell a man to only say Kaddish once, since it does not feel right that the Minyan has to wait a few times for him to say Kaddish?

Comment: @GershonGold Certainly. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36557/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34845/759 Delaying the Tzibbur for that probably does more harm than good for the Neshama, but sadly people nowadays are often focused too much on themselves to care.

Comment: @DoubleAA: You are taking my point out of context. Yes there is discussion as to whether a man should only say Kaddish once. My point was that a woman should not be held to a different standard than a man. If a Shul would tell a man to only say Kaddish once, yes, then you should tell a woman to only say it once, however if you allow a man to say it multiple times, (which the majority of the Shul's do allow) then why should a woman be different?

Comment: @Gershon you just conflated allow and should. Someone who doesn't say kaddish after anim zmirot but only after Shir shel yom, and goes to a shul that does both doesn't need to say then just because the shul allows it. Same for many others. Shuls mostly don't want to annoy mourners so they allow much more than is recommended, and most mourners mistakenly think they should be trying to get as many kaddishes as possible

Answer (score 0):

Both the Mishna Brura and the Be'er Heitev in [סימן נה - דיני קדיש](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0009_L2) write that ***the fewer the better*, when it comes to saying Kaddish.**  This is true whether the person is a man or a woman -- a woman says it as often as a man, i.e. once per Tefilah.

> כאשר טוב למעט בברכות כך טוב למעט בקדישין כה''ג ‏

Comment: If only a woman in the shul is saying Kaddish, does she say it once or every time that the siddur says Kaddish yasom (the Kaddish for mourners)?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Once (or never if you hold her saying it alone is not Tznuah). The Siddur prints it multiple times for places that have multiple mourners but allow for only one person per Kaddish

Comment: Surely that means that it shouldn't be said at all?

Comment: @Moses you have to say it after a public study session. The minimization is to not make repeated small study sessions to be able to say kaddish multiple times. Same reason you don't say a new kaddish after every three psukim in shir shel yom.

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant that if we're taking "the fewer the better" at face value then 0 would be optimal so clearly it isn't quite as simple as that

Comment: @Moses 0 extra is indeed optimal