# Should one recite Mourner's Kaddish between the daily Psalm and Psalm 27?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, tehilim-psalms, kaddish, elul

I've seen different activities done in two Nusach Ashkenaz shuls at the end of SHacahrit between 1 Elul and Shmini Atzeret.

One shul says two Mourner's Kaddish - one after the daily Psalm and another after Psalm 27.

Another says the daily Psalm, then Psalm 27 with one Kaddish at the end.

Is there any correct way, or are both acceptable? Why would there be a debate on this? Is there any support for either custom?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7283/759

Answer (score 4):

In principle [you could say Kaddish on just a couple verses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81345/759), but you don't usually see people stopping after every few lines of the daily Psalm to say Kaddish because the general rule* is to always minimize the number of times Kaddish is said. So if there is only one mourner (or multiple mourners who are going to say Kaddish together) then say one Kaddish at the end, and if there are multiple mourners who each want their own Kaddish then stick another one in the middle at a reasonable stopping point. This logic applies to any series of verses/study after which Kaddish is to be said (eg. Alenu *and* Shir Shel Yom *and* Barkhi Nafshi etc.). (See [Teshuvot Ivra 1:4:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22080&st=&pgnum=23) who makes this point.)

<sub>*Keneset HaGedola [OC 55](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14598&st=&pgnum=28), Beir Heitev [OC 55 sk 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x422), Maaseh Rav [53](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31538&st=&pgnum=18), Chayei Adam [30:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51658&st=&pgnum=276), Mishna Berura [55 sk 1](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.55.1), Arukh HaShulchan [OC 55:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%94#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92), Kaf HaChayim [OC 55 sk 8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&st=&pgnum=189), Chida (Kesher Gadol [8:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34941&st=&pgnum=14), Birkei Yosef [OC 132](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7626&st=&pgnum=73)), Ben Ish Chai [Vayechi 1:9](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99#.D7.98), KSA Yalkut Yosef [2:264:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.2.264.2), Shethilei Zeithim [OC 55 sk 6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40528&st=&pgnum=95), Shaar HaKolel [11:29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16002&st=&pgnum=60)</sub>