# What are the minimum amount of tehillim (psalms) one must recite before concluding with kaddish?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, kaddish, minyan

For example many on shabbbos mevarchim recite all of tehillim and when someone finishes a book kaddish kaddish is recited.

Does it need to be a whole book for kaddish to be said or is there another amount that is the minimum amount of tehillim that must be said?

Comment: No source, but you only need one kapitel Tehillim to say a kaddish. I said kaddish for my maternal grandfather on my mother's behalf today (my parents have both given me reshuyot to say קדיש יתום ודרבנן) and because as Jekkes, we don't say Kaddish after 'Aleinu, I recited some tehillim at that point to say a kaddish by minchah

Comment: @noac I don't think that's accurate. I think 3 verses should be sufficient

Comment: so saying Tehillim 117 wouldn't be enough?

Comment: @danno According to some opinions no. When I said three I didn't mean everyone held that way, just that it would be the most needed.

Comment: @DoubleAA, 3 pesukim of Tanach, Ketuvim, or Tehillim?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Tanakh (we say Kaddish after Megillot, for instance). I'm busy this week but I will hopefully write up an answer next week.

Answer (score 1):

Over Pesach, I came across the Kol Bo ([Siman 6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45043&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=)) who writes that one may say kaddish after 3 or more of "pesukim of praise or other pesukim":

> ואחר ישתבח פותח החזן קדיש, שכן דרך הקדיש לבא אחר קריאת פסוקים או אחר דרשה ... אך טוב שיאמר פסוקי דתהלה או שאר פסוקים עד ג' או יותר ואח"כ יאמר קדיש